# Reference Error when using Send Grid with my Angular2 Typescript app

Tags: javascript, sendgrid

I'm using npm install sendgrid for my Angular 2 Typescript app.

I've installed sendgrid and the package but I keep getting a console error:

"ReferenceError: require is not defined"

**This is an example of my code(I've removed the key for obvious reasons):**

```
  var sendgrid_api_key = "key goes here";

  var sendgrid  = require('sendgrid')(sendgrid_api_key);

  sendgrid.send({
    to:       'mark@gmail.com',
    from:     'support@gmail.com',
    subject:  'Hello Mark Test',
    text:     'My first email through SendGrid.'
  }, function(err, json) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
      console.log(json);
  });
```

Comment: How is this related to Angular?

Comment: I'm using send grid in my angular 2 project, do you know how to get send grid working in this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use SendGrid from client-side code. It's inherently insecure because anyone can look at the code and get your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

require() is server side only (i.e. Node), it does not exist in the client/browser javascript.  Ensure you are running your Angular2 app through SystemJS or Webpack for example.

Comment: Hi Tim,

For my app I have no server side. I'm using SystemJS. 

Is it possible to get send grid working client side only?

Comment: This is where I got the example from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendgrid - but I dont have node js. Any other ideas?

Comment: Would assume so. Try `import * as sendgrid from ('sendgrid')` and include the sendgrid js dependencies in your initial html.

Comment: What would the import be? and where can I get the send grid js from?

Comment: replace the `require` with the `import` above.  Run `npm i sendgrid --save` to install it into your `node_modules` directory, the js will be there.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. So far I've installed npm send grid

Can you change the code above?

Comment: No, it sounds like you need a firmer understanding of javascript and the tools you are using.  Suggest you study the basics before tackling 'sendgrid'.  Ask specific questions in other threads, this post is not the place to do it.

Comment: Can't you update the code above for me and I should be fine?

Comment: Yes, but it will cost you $10000